# "use of partially moved value" error in "match" statement

Tags: rust

My code:

```
fn main() {
    let mut messages = vec![];

    let msg = Message::Write{message: "msg".to_string()};
    match msg {
        Message::Write{message} => println!("{}", message),
    };

    messages.push(msg);
}

enum Message {
    Write{message: String},
}
```

The error:

```
error: use of partially moved value: `msg` [--explain E0382]
   --> <anon>:9:19
6   |>         Message::Write{message} => println!("{}", message),
    |>                        ------- value moved here
...
9   |>     messages.push(msg);
    |>                   ^^^ value used here after move
note: move occurs because `msg.message` has type `std::string::String`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

error: aborting due to previous error
```

It looks like the ownership of the `message` field changes in the `match` block.  I just want to be able to output the value of the enum before adding it to the `Vec`.  How do I make this compile?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Bind to the `message` field by-reference instead of by-value.

```rust
    match msg {
        Message::Write{ref message} => println!("{}", message),
    };
```

Comment: That worked, thank you!  I've never seen "ref" before.  Can that only be used in "match" blocks?  What's the difference between "ref" and "&"?

Comment: @Michael [`ref` is used in patterns](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/patterns.html#ref-and-ref-mut) to bind to a position by reference.  `&` in pattern position is used to *deconstruct* a reference, allowing you to access or bind to the position *behind* it.

Comment: [This article](http://xion.io/post/code/rust-patterns-ref.html) might help understand the difference.