# Avoid using partially moved value in match statement

Tags: rust, switch-statement, borrow-checker

The solution provided in question [38553513](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38553513/use-of-partially-moved-value-error-in-match-statement) does not work for me.

Consider these types and functions:

```
pub enum Parameter {
    ParameterTypeA { n: i32 },
    ParameterTypeB { s: String },
}

pub struct Res {
    pub param: Parameter,
    pub res: i32,
}

n use_string(_: String) -> i32 {
    return 23;
}

fn use_int(_: i32) -> i32 {
    return 42;
}
```

What I wanted to achieve was this:

```
fn foobar(p: Parameter) -> std::result::Result<Res, String> {
    return match p {
        Parameter::ParameterTypeA { n } => { Ok(Result { param: p, res: use_int(n) }) }
        Parameter::ParameterTypeB { s } => { Ok(Result { param: p, res: use_string(s) }) }
    };
}
```

But the compiler complained about `Parameter::ParameterTypeB { s }` being partially moved and refuses to use it with `param: p`.

According to the compiler's suggestion and the mentioned SO thread, I changed the second match to

```
Parameter::ParameterTypeB { ref s } => { Ok(Result { param: p, res: use_string(s.to_string()) }) }
```

but again, the compiler complains that `{ref s}` borrows `p.s` which cannot be moved while creating the result.

How is should this problem be solved? Please understand, modifying the function signatures or data types is not an option.

MVE available at [play.rust-lang.org](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3d63404d8b3edaab1d6041f407576168).

Comment: With the code as written, it's impossible without cloning, since both `use_str` and `Result` need ownership of the `String`. Do you want to avoid it specifically?

Comment: Cerberus: I do not like cloning too much for obvious reasons. I was hoping that there was a solution without, but well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most idiomatic way to fix this would be to change the signature of `use_string` so that it takes a `&str` instead of a `String`:

```
pub enum Parameter {
    ParameterTypeA { n: i32 },
    ParameterTypeB { s: String },
}

pub struct Res {
    pub param: Parameter,
    pub res: i32,
}

fn use_string(_: &str) -> i32 {
    return 23;
}

fn use_int(_: i32) -> i32 {
    return 42;
}

fn foobar(p: Parameter) -> std::result::Result<Res, String> {
    return match p {
        Parameter::ParameterTypeA { n } => { Ok(Res { param: p, res: use_int(n) }) }
        Parameter::ParameterTypeB { ref s } => { Ok(Res { res: use_string (s), param: p }) }
    };
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=cf74dd2a92659b4a20d44cfa107fd465)

Note that I've changed the order of `res` and `param` so that `res` comes first when instantiating `Res`. This is because they are evaluated from left to right, and having `param: p` first would move `p` and make it impossible to use `s` (which borrows `p`) in the subsequent call to `use_string`.

Since you state that changing the signature is not an option, you will need to clone the string so that `p` retains a copy after the call to `use_string`:

```
pub enum Parameter {
    ParameterTypeA { n: i32 },
    ParameterTypeB { s: String },
}

pub struct Res {
    pub param: Parameter,
    pub res: i32,
}

fn use_string(_: String) -> i32 {
    return 23;
}

fn use_int(_: i32) -> i32 {
    return 42;
}

fn foobar(p: Parameter) -> std::result::Result<Res, String> {
    return match p {
        Parameter::ParameterTypeA { n } => { Ok(Res { param: p, res: use_int(n) }) }
        Parameter::ParameterTypeB { ref s } => { Ok(Res { res: use_string (s.clone()), param: p }) }
    };
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=b4f7b07f4b5842609397ffe0a88e795f)